# Grails 3.1.2 wont run Error org.hibernate.hbm2ddl.schemaupdate - hhh000388

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, yaml

I have been recreating an old app from 2.2.2 to 3.1.2
The following below is the error I am getting because of a database problem.
So far I have not found a solution online about this major error. Grails will not run while the errors exist.
I am fairly new to grails and as such am unsure about the errors listed below. any help will be greatly appreciated.
Using:
Grails Version: 3.1.2
MySQL Workbench 6

```
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table location (id bigint not null auto_
    increment, version bigint not null, location varchar(255) not null, specific varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) EN
    GINE=InnoDB
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'specific varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=
    InnoDB' at line 1
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table update (id bigint not null auto_in
    crement, version bigint not null, asset_id bigint not null, location_id bigint not null, note varchar(1000), occurred_at
     datetime not null, occurred_by_id bigint not null, state_id bigint not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint
     not null, asset_id big' at line 1
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table update add constraint FK_6xengovrbl
    vcx3o2p48wii9up foreign key (asset_id) references asset (id)
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update add constraint FK_6xengovrblvcx3o2p48wii9up foreig
    n key (asset_id) refere' at line 1
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table update add constraint FK_qlyn7y3hqg
    n4gcyidimltadkt foreign key (location_id) references location (id)
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update add constraint FK_qlyn7y3hqgn4gcyidimltadkt foreig
    n key (location_id) ref' at line 1
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table update add constraint FK_7bbvhf1v8f
    5ajhqq9oucd8fsq foreign key (occurred_by_id) references user (id)
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update add constraint FK_7bbvhf1v8f5ajhqq9oucd8fsq foreig
    n key (occurred_by_id) ' at line 1
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table update add constraint FK_p07l6jl32s
    obfymx3otspk2t3 foreign key (state_id) references state (id)
    ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update add constraint FK_p07l6jl32sobfymx3otspk2t3 foreig
    n key (state_id) refere' at line 1
    ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
    - Field error in object 'State' on field 'updates': rejected value [{}]; codes [State.updates.typeMismatch.error,State.u
    pdates.typeMismatch,state.updates.typeMismatch.error,state.updates.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.State.updates,typeMismatch.
    updates,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [updates]; default message [Could not find matching construc
    tor for: java.util.Set()]

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8
    .0_65]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075) ~
    [springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77) ~[groovy-2.4.
    6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1714) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1531) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf(InvokerHelper.java:954) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.
    6]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newInstance(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15640) ~[groovy-2.4.6.
    jar:2.4.6]
            at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:131) ~
    [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:140) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-5.0.2.R
    ELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at State.save(State.groovy) ~[main/:na]
            at State.save(State.groovy) ~[main/:na]
            at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:10) ~[main/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloa
    ded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.6
    .jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
            at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:437) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3
    .1.2]
            at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:430) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:406) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2
    ]
            at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62) ~[g
    rails-web-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65) ~[grails-
    web-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53) ~[grail
    s-plugin-controllers-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:24
    0) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy) ~
    [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMult
    icaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMult
    icaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:3
    81) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:3
    35) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
    855) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationC
    ontext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~
    [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
    .java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.ja
    r:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-
    1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.
    3.2.RELEASE]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
    ]
            at Application.main(Application.groovy:6) [main/:na]
```

My application.yml that I am recoding is this:

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
    dataSource:
    pooled: true
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: root

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

the DataSource.groovy of old app that I am basing on is this:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {

        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harbor"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
            properties {
                maxActive = 100
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 5
                initialSize = 10
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
                maxWait = 10000
            }
        }

        /*dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }*/
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource { 
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
            properties {
                maxActive = 100
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 5
                initialSize = 10
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
                maxWait = 10000
            }
        }

        /*
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application.yml of mine now

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: grailsapp
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: root

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory
    test:
        dataSource:
            driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
            username: sa
            password:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first line of your errors, it looks like one of your data classes has an attribute named 'specific'.

Unfortunately, that is a MySQL reserved word so you can't use it.  You'll need to change the name of the field.

Similarly, your second error is for a table called 'update', which is also a reserved word.

For a list of reserved words see, for example, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.  You may be on an older version of MySQL, but as they point out it's always good to check reserved words on later versions so you don't make it difficult to upgrade to that version of MySQL later.

As an alternative to renaming things, you should be able to tell Grails to escape the names.  See for example, http://blog.adamcreeger.com/2010/05/random-grails-tip-using-db-reserved.html